How to solve the error "Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement"?
I got a table named Customer with column ID as AUTO NUMBER, Names as Short Text, Phone as Short Text, Age as Number, Deposit as Number. I still can't figure out why this error keep popping out.
Try
    conn.Open()
    cmd = conn.CreateCommand()
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Customer(Names, Phone, Age, Deposit) VALUES(@Name, @Phone, @Age, @Deposit)"
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", txtName.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Phone", txtPhone.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Age", txtAge.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Deposit", txtDeposit.Text)
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

    conn.Close()
    MessageBox.Show("Customer is registered into the database", "Customer Registration", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)

    txtName.Text = String.Empty
    txtPhone.Text = String.Empty
    txtAge.Text = String.Empty
    txtDeposit.Text = String.Empty
Catch ex As Exception
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Uh Oh...", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    conn.Close()
End Try

Table design of Customer
I've tried with and without parameter, still return the same error, I've reconnected the Database for several times, also not working.

@Gustav I'm not entirely sure how that duplicate applies to this question about a syntax error. Could you explain?

@ErikA: Most likely, the two numeric values are read as text and attempted to be inserted like that as AddWithValue tries to read the data type from the passed input.

Thanks! I'm not sure that can lead to a syntax error, but it's certainly worthwhile to switch to Add regardless of any errors.
